# Returns resource units currently seized by this agent But for Transporters

Tags: anylogic

resourceUnitsOfSeize (Agent Seize); Returns resource units currently seized by this agent from the given ResourcePool block. But if I have TransporterFleet instead of resourcePool what is the alternative code to get the transporter unit currently seized by this agent?

I have a trench agent which is a material type agnet. It siezed an excavator from excavatorFleet in a transpoter flow block called seizeExc. So I used the following function and I got the following error:  I tried to use the same code but it did not work.  [image]

[image]

How to do this please? Thanks.

Second Error:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The same code is working for any Seize block. I changed the Return Value type to other; **List of Excavator**, and I typed `return resourceUnitsOfSeize(seizeExc);`

instead of  `return trenchRoom.resourceUnitsOfSeize(seizeExc);`

Also for the same purpose, we can use another function with the following properties:
Type: **Collection ResourceRequest** and Function body: `return excavatorFleet.getRequests();`

Hopefully In both cases I can get transporters that have been seized by a trenchRoom agent.

:)